# Ребята, кто сталкивался с созданием клиента pyrogram и авторизацией в телеграмме, хелпаните пожалуйста!

Tags: python, asyncio, pyrogram

Возникла проблема с использованием кода из смс при авторизации clieta telegramm, а именно я не могу понять почему у меня не вызывается функция с этим кодом из моего модуля, ниже предоставляю код:

Код телеграмм бота, которым я хочу заменить ввод кода в терминале:

```
class AccountManagementStateFSM(StatesGroup):
    auth_account_code = State()

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == " Авторизация аккаунта")
async def auth_account_handler(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Введите код авторизации:')
    await AccountManagementStateFSM.auth_account_code.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=AccountManagementStateFSM.auth_account_code)
async def process_auth_code(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        data['auth_code'] = message.text
        await shared.auth_code_queue.put(data['auth_code'])
        print(f"Код добавлен в auth_code_queue: {data['auth_code']}")
        await state.finish()
        await message.answer('Спасибо! Код авторизации получен.')
```

Модуль shared который я использую для обработки кода:

```
import logging
from asyncio import Queue

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

auth_code_queue = Queue()


async def code_callback():
    try:
        code = await auth_code_queue.get()
        logger.debug(f"Получен код аутентификации из очереди: {code}")
        return code
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Произошла ошибка в code_callback: {e}")
        return None
```

И сам скрипт:

```
async def update_tags(queue):
    while True:
        accounts = apidb.get_accounts()
        new_accounts = await queue.get()
        for account in accounts + new_accounts:
            api_id = account['api_id']
            api_hash = account['api_hash']
            acc_name = account['acc_name']
            phone_number = account['number']
            last_changed_tag = {}

            file_path = f'{acc_name}_last_changed_tags.json'
            if os.path.exists(file_path):
                with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
                    last_changed_tag = json.load(f)
            else:
                last_changed_tag = {}

            async with Client(phone_number=phone_number, api_id=api_id, api_hash=api_hash, name=acc_name) as client_obj:
                await client_obj.send_code()
                try:
                    auth_code = await shared.code_callback()
                    print(f"Получен код аутентификации: {auth_code}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Произошла ошибка при получении кода: {e}")

                # Передача кода аутентификации в функцию аутентификации
                await client_obj.sign_in(code=auth_code)
                print("Аутентификация завершена")

                for group_name in account['group_name']:
                    last_tag = last_changed_tag.get(group_name, group_name)
                    if last_tag != group_name:
                        await change_group_tag(client_obj, group_name, last_changed_tag, acc_name)

                await client_obj.disconnect()

            with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
                json.dump(last_changed_tag, f)

        await asyncio.sleep(1800)
```

Проблема в вызове функции coda_callblack, я не могу понять что не так, отладочное сообщение выводится только одно, "print(f"Код добавлен в auth_code_queue: {data['auth_code']}")" больше не какие сообщения не печатаются.

Ошибок нету, после ввода кода из смс в боте, авторизация дальше не идет, программа ожидает код.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). особенно в части про заголовок.